# How to use single package.json file within MEAN stack app (Angular 4 & Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, package.json

I'm building a MEAN Stack app with Angular 4. As you know angular comes with its own `package.json` file and Node/Express App has its own `package.json` file.

I want to have a single `package.json` file within my app but I am not sure how to proceed with this.

**My Structure:**

1. My `package.json` file for **Angular 4** is in the `angular-src` folder
2. My `package.json` file for **Node/Express** app at the root of my project

[image]

This also means I have 2 `node_modules` files one for angular 4 modules and the other for node/express modules.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have exactly the same problem